# how to make a user restrict to download?

Tags: php, html

I know this question is silly.

But as per our intelligent Client request, I am not able to answer his question. Any one help for this.

We are building a online tutoring site. where it contains pdf, .ppt, .doc formats files are uploaded for reading as course materials. His (Client) request is that user can read all the contents but they must not download the materials and use this.

That is all the documents must be opened in their browsers.

Is it possible? Any other ideas?

Comment: This again? It's been asked under so many covers I find it hard to point a dupe. However, the answer is the same as "how do I travel back in time": You can't.

Comment: The short answer is "no".  The long answer is "no, you can't".

Comment: You know who said "The Customer is Always Right"? Yeah... That guy was wrong.

Comment: Should go to your client and say "Sorry, Can't do it. I asked on StackOverflow and too many people downvoted it."

Comment: Thank you for all your Answers, I may take this down Votes is for my Client not for me.

Comment: Not sure why this question is being downvoted.  It's a legitimate question, it's just that the client's request is ridiculous and the answer is "it's impossible".

Comment: @Jeff Oh, the client is being ridiculous? What a finding.

Comment: Normally StackOverflow questions don't have 'opinions' in them, MetaOverflow does. So the voting style of Meta is being transferred to StackOverflow, where people vote upon premise rather than if its a good question.

Comment: I believe lots of downvotes are (rather stupid and unhelpful) ways of answering no.

Comment: I'd probably upvote it if it wasn't past the lockout time. The question has gathered up some very useful conversation.

Comment: There we go, reset the lockout.

Comment: Customers have ridiculous requirements.  Finding solutions is sometimes called innovation.

Comment: Doing something over and over again and expecting a new result is called insanity. And DRM has been tried over and over again, and it isn't getting a new result anytime soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any other ideas?

Explain to your client that the only way for a document to appear on a user's computer screen is for the document to exist on that user's computer.

In other words, viewing a document *involves* downloading it. Even supposing the software on the user's computer somehow makes it impossible for the user to directly manipulate an electronic copy of the material, the user can take out a digital camera and take a picture of the screen.

There are ways to make it *difficult* for the user to save a copy of the file. However, it's likely that this will do more harm (frustrating users) than good (preventing theft).

Some users may want to peruse the material at times when they do not have an internet connection, or may want to copy it onto their mobile device (for instance), but accessing the internet on their mobile device is expensive so they would like to do the download on their computer.

Comment: Also content thieves are smart and can bypass lame "protection", wile end users are dumb and blame the website to be hard to use. This doens't stop stupid "right-click protectors"

Comment: Thank you for all and your's interesting answers. I am now feel a little free with your answers.

Answer (score 5):

If you send the data to the client the client has effectively downloaded it. You can make this difficult, but not impossible.

The only sure way to prevent downloading is to prevent viewing.

If this is a copyright problem it should be solved with legalese, not software.

Comment: "If it can be read, it can be copied." -- A guy I knew in high school and forgot his name.  I have yet to find an effective exception to this rule.

Comment: There probably isn't any, because if you can read it, you can write down what you are thinking as you read it. Somehow you brains processes it into words, and words can be written.

Comment: I use a similar self-quoted axiom in security contexts: "If someone can, someone else can".

Comment: This is the same thing music labels won't understand soon. DRM is as useless and harmful to business as it can be (I would never buy anything copy-protected! how stupid those lawyers are.)

Comment: Yeah, Digital Intellectual Property is still being held onto by the old business folks. No longer are we in the world of physical media, where 1 CD = 1 Set of Songs.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the docs into Google docs and embed the [docs viewer](https://drive.googleblog.com/2009/09/view-online-files-using-google-docs.html) into your site. Of course, there's no stopping people from taking screenshots, copy/pasting text, downloading HTML, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some guide-lines you may consider:

1. Don't put direct link of files such as:

   ```
   <a href="mydoc.pdf">Download</a>
   ```

Instead, try to generate your pdf dynamically or put a another encrypted medium for
downloading eg:

```
<a href="download.php?file_id=1111111">Download</a>
```

2: Don't allow directory browsing, use htaccess file with following commands:

```
 Deny from ALL
```

3: Not sure, but you may possibly allow file opening this way too:

```
$filename="/path/to/file.jpg"; //<-- specify the image  file
if(file_exists($filename)){ 
 header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename])); //<-- sends filesize header
 header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); //<-- send mime-type header
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'";'); //<-- sends filename     header
 readfile($filename); //<--reads and outputs the file onto the output buffer

 exit; //and exit
}
```

**Note:** above is just an example of image not pdf but you can modify it for your needs.

Comment: Wait .. die and **then** exit? makes no sense.

Comment: Please mention the fact your code is Perl (it is Perl, right?). Not being a Perl literate I had some trouble figuring that out. It was the die thing that called out.

Comment: Oops, it's PHP. I think I should go to sleep now.

Comment: die() is a functional command in PHP. It just happens to do the same thing as exit.. except it will print a message passed into it.

Answer (score 2):

An online site does not necessarily mean it is a web site. You could write a custom client that accesses the data and displays it.

The data would need to be encrypted between the client and the server.  It probably should not be sent 'in bulk' either.

The effort associated with developing that is prohibitive.

You could license the software that allows users to read books, page by page, that is part of the [Safari Books Online](http://safaribooksonline.com/Corporate/Index/) web site.

As best I can tell, they take the pages that they are going to display and turn them into small images.  These images look as if they are sent in a random order, and assembled by the browser via javascript.

These tactics won't stop a determined person from getting your clients content... but the effort is unlikely to be worth it.

Comment: The goal is to make sure that any effort required of honest users (like installing a dedicate client) is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "read" but not "download"?? Do you know that even if you disable cache (which by itself is a bad idea) won't restrict an eaaaasy right-click>view source, "save target as", etc.?

I mean, the best you can have is a flash reader that is harder to save the content from, and that means disabling selection and copying, but anyway, it doesn't forbid anything.

The only way to forbid download is to return HTTP 403 :)